# index.html not loading by default

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

i have Ubuntu 18.04 and have Apache 2.4.29

i have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blah.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  ...
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in `/var/www/html/test` i have `index.html`

but when I go to `blah.com/test/` it shows me a `403 Forbidden` error. I can however go to `blah.com/test/index.html` and it loads the page.

Any ideas where I can look to see what option i'm missing? thanks

Comment: Hi, is `DocumentRoot` directive there?

Comment: yes sorry. added it in my example

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

try this code

```
403 Forbidden  its mean you don't have permission
```

maybe its help to you

> check you .htaccess as well

Comment: it does have user/group permission for www-data and 755 for directory and 644 for the file. There is no .htaccess as well